# Python DateTimeType sybase

Tags: python, database

When I use the python Sybase package, and do a cursor fetch(), one of the columns is a datetime - in the sequence returned, it has a DateTimeType object for this value.
I can find it is in the sybasect module but can't find any documentation for this datatype.
I would like to be able to convert it to a string output - similar to using strftime() with datetime objects.
Any info on this?

Comment: You could do a dir() on it to see what methods/attributes it has.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to install the [egenix-mx-base](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/egenix-mx-base) package. This will make the [mxDateTime](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/doc/%5d) module available to the `sybase` package and by default *all datetime columns will then be returned as `mxDateTime.DateTime` objects* (quoted from the `sybase` package documentation).

As you'll be able to verify in the [mxDateTime](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/doc/%5d) documentation, it will then be trivial to obtain your string output.

Answer (score 1):

The core problem is a difference in how months are specified in the DateTimeType object vs in the datetime objects.

I've written a little function to handle this issue. That way no additional modules need to be installed nor additional DateTime conversions are required.

Any improvements to the code are welcome :-)

```
def ps_datetime_converter(date_time_type_object):
    # Convert from python-sybase DateTimeType format (months 0 to 11) to datetime type format
    try:
        dt_kwargs = {}
        dt_kwargs['year'] = date_time_type_object.year
        dt_kwargs['month'] = date_time_type_object.month + 1
        dt_kwargs['day'] = date_time_type_object.day
        dt_kwargs['hour'] = date_time_type_object.hour
        dt_kwargs['minute'] = date_time_type_object.minute
        dt_kwargs['second'] = date_time_type_object.second
        dt_kwargs['microsecond'] = date_time_type_object.msecond
        date_time_object = datetime(**dt_kwargs)
        return date_time_object
    except:
        print "Conversion from DateTimeType object to datetime object failed."
```